# Setting the value of a Picker to index of object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, state

I have a view called EditEventView(), which is displayed as a sheet, and has two objects passed into it; `Team` and `Match Event`. Inside the match event object, I store an attribute of type `Player`, these players can also be found using `team.players`.

Inside this new sheet view, I have some PickerViews which should show all the players of a `Team` object, the user can then select one and it's assigned to the Match Event. When I loaded into this view I wanted the `@State` variable to be set to the index of these players, rather than 0, which they are set at currently. However I believe it is impossible to change these states' values inside the view, and I don't have enough knowledge of `init` functions to look at this.

This is an abbreviated version of EditEventView():

```
struct EditEventView: View {
    @ObservedObject var team: Team
    @State var event: MatchEvent

    @State var playerSelect = 0

    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Picker(selection: $playerSelect, label: Text("Player Off")) {
                    ForEach(0..<team.players.count) {
                        Text("\(team.players[$0].shirtNumber) - \(team.players[$0].playerName)")
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Select Player Off")
                }
```

This view is shown using:

```
Button(action: {self.event = event}) {
    MainEventBox(event: event)
}
.sheet(item: self.$event){ event in
    EditEventView(team: event.team, event: event)
}
```

Match Event is a struct, like this:

```
struct MatchEvent: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var team: Team
    var player: Player
    var eventType: eventType
}
```

Each Team is structured like this:

```
class Team: ObservableObject{
    @Published var players: [Player] = [Player(playerName: "", shirtNumber: 1, active: true),
                                        Player(playerName: "", shirtNumber: 2, active: true),
                                        Player(playerName: "", shirtNumber: 3, active: true)....]
    
    func findPlayer(player: Player) -> Int?{
        var i: Int = 0
        for x in self.players{
            if x.id == player.id{
                return i
            }
            i += 1
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

I believe that I would have to initialize the view and set the value of `playerSelect` to the result of `team.findPlayer(player: event.player)`. However, I'm not sure and may be completely wrong!
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "I have a view called EditEventView(), which is called a sheet"  Que!?  You mean, you have a view called EditEventView(), which calls a sheet?  If so, where is the sheet?

Comment: Which is displayed as a sheet sorry, I have corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can initialize the state var:

```
    @ObservedObject private var team: Team
    @State private var event: MatchEvent
    @State private var playerSelect

    init(team: Team, event: MatchEvent) {
        self.team = team
        self._event = State(initialValue: event)
        let playerSelect = team.findPlayer(player: event.player)
        self._playerSelect = State(initialValue: playerSelect)
    }
```